# Python: printing a set using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, set

I have to change a list to a set and a powerset using recursion. My code works on the powerset, but I cannot get it to work on the set that we began with.

Code:

```
def printSet (A):

    if type(A) == int:
        return A
    elif len(A) == 1:
        return {}
    else:
        elementA = A.pop()
        return  str(printSet(A))+ ',' + str(set(elementA))
        print('{' + str(printSet(A)),end='}');
```

I can get the code to work for the second example below, but not for the first example below:

```
>>> printSet ([1,2,3,4])
{1, 2, 3, 4}

>>> printSet ([[1,2], [1,3]]
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}}
```

The input is:
  Params: A (list): set of integers, represented internally as a list

The output is to print a set in standard set notation.

Comment: Can you please explain what your intended output is?

Comment: Can you fix your indentation please? And explain a bit better your desired input/output?

Answer (score 0):

A powerset is defined as `P(s) = {{}, {s_1}, {s_2}, ... {s_1, s_2},.., s}`. To implement it in recursion, it is best to use a generator expressions. Also, sets are not hashable in Python, therefore, you will have to create your own set wrapper:

```
class WrapperSet:
  def __init__(self, *args):
     self.val = set() if not args else args
  def __repr__(self):
     return "{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__, str(self))
  def __str__(self):
     return '{'+', '.join(map(str, self.val))+'}'

def get_result(s):
   result = list(p(s))
   current = sorted([a for i, a in enumerate(result) if a not in result[:i]], key=len)       
   return WrapperSet(*[WrapperSet(), *[WrapperSet(*i) for i in current]])

def p(s, current = []):
  if len(s) == len(current):
    yield current
  else:
   for i in s:
     yield [i]
     if i in current:
       yield current
     else:
       yield from p(s, sorted(current+[i]))
```

Output:

```
print(get_result([1, 2, 3]))
```

Output:

```
WrapperSet({{}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}})
```